# Create single BINARY_CHECKSUM from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, checksum

I have a simple query that returns multiple rows:

```
Select make, model, colour From Vehicles
```

I want to create a single BINARY_CHECKSUM from the results, but because the query returns more than 1 row, I get a BINARY_CHECKSUM for each row, whereas I want a single BINARY_CHECKSUM for the full result set.

```
Select BINARY_CHECKSUM(make, model, colour) From Vehicles
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: From what I have read, binary checksum is intended to be a row-level function.

Comment: Do you know how I could create some kind of single checksum for the whole result set?

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but I don't know this API at all.  Roughly speaking, you may query to see if your current vehicles table contains any records with checksums which did not appear in a previous version of the table.

Comment: I get what your saying but not what im trying to achieve. I just need a single checksum for the whole result set. Without going into too much detail, I had two tables which should have identical data meeting my where criteria, so I wanted to create a checksum of each then compare the checksums to confirm if their the same or different, but this cannot be done on a per row level

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in general.  But we can write a query to do this check easily enough.

Comment: I know there are other ways to do the kind of thing im looking to do, but unfortunately I am restricted that it needs to be done with a single checksum for each result set

Comment: I have been working with SQL and data for a very long time, and I have never had the need for this.  So, maybe your design is off and you should rethink it.

Comment: The reason for needing to do this is outside of my control, yes we should have done things in development differently, to completly remove the need for this, but it is what it is and I am left with no choice but to find an answer under the current setup. I am just trying SELECT  CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(.... which looks like it may do what I need

Comment: Thanks, I believe SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(.... is doing the job for me, I just need to test the hell out of changing data in the table, once confirmed il post it as the answer if I havn't had any other suggestions to look into

Comment: OK, if you come up with something viable, and you want to share, then consider answering your own question (yes; it's possible to do that).